# Scrolltop offset top issue

Tags: jquery, html

I used the below mentioned code for scrolling to a div. I applied `scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-250` in the mobile view so that the section will display below the header height, but it seems it does not work.

```js
$('#portfolioNavbar ul li a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250
  }, 600, function() {
    location.hash = target; //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: `But it seems not working` In what way is it not working?

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated. You should be using `on()` instead. Also check your version of jQuery, you should be using v3.x at least

Comment: I mean `top - 250` is not working. and using latest jquery too.

Comment: Did you get something when doing `console.log($(target).offset())`?

Comment: `console.log( jQuery('#portfolioNavbar ul li a[href*=#]') );` does return your bound elements?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio yes it is returning bound elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script saved my time. This script may be useful for others.

```
$('#portfolioNavbar ul li a').click(function() {
     var tghsh = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
     var headerHeight = $('.portfolioi_left').outerHeight();
     var winwid = $(window).width();
     var doffset = $('#'+tghsh).offset().top-20;
     var doffset1 = $('#'+tghsh).offset().top-280;
     if(winwid <= 991) {
         doffset1 -= headerHeight;
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:doffset1},700);
     return false;
     }
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:doffset},700);
     return false;
});
```

If want to make menu active on the scroll to div. can you this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#portfolioNavbar ul li a').click(function() {
     $(document).off("scroll");

    $('#portfolioNavbar ul li a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');
     var tghsh = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
     var headerHeight = $('.portfolioi_left').outerHeight();
     var winwid = $(window).width();
     var doffset = $('#'+tghsh).offset().top-20;
     var doffset1 = $('#'+tghsh).offset().top-280;
     if(winwid <= 991) {
         doffset1 -= headerHeight;
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:doffset1},700);
     return false;
     }
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:doffset},700);
     return false;
});
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#portfolioNavbar ul li a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#portfolioNavbar ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
};
```