# Scroll to top of the div counting navbar height

Tags: html, css

I want scroll page to the top of section EXACTLY. I mean counting navigation bar height, and where section starts, should be displayed under of navigation bar. But in my case these sections are behind the nav. (Btw, I am scrolling to div by id and href, I think I should write some js codes).

HTML:

```
<div class="right-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a data-scroll="header" href="#header-section" class="active-nav">Ana səhifə</a></li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="about" href="#about-section">Layihə</a></li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="terms" href="#terms-section">Qəbul şərtləri</a></li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="attendants" href="#attendants-section">İştirakçılar</a></li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="most-asked" href="#most-asked-section">Sual-cavab</a></li>
                        <li><a data-scroll="contact" href="#contact-section">Əlaqə</a></li>
                        <li><button class="apply-button " id="popup-opener">Müraciət et</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

```
<section id="about-section" data-anchor="about">

            <div class="left-side-about">
                <img src="img/undraw-developer-activity.svg" alt="Image not found :/">
            </div>

            <div class="right-side-about">
                <span>CHALLENGERS CLUB</span>
                <h2>Bizim Haqqımızda</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                    leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
            </div>

        </section>
```

CSS:

```
#about-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 80px 0px;
}
```

```
.pc-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 14px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `position: fixed` on your navbar which means that you need to add a `top-margin` on your first following elmenet, of the equal distance as your navbar height. However, without you providing any code, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Can you update the question with a code so that we can know what you have done so far and maybe we can give a solution in the best way

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278273/scrolltop-offset-top-issue/55279868#55279868) can be help ful for you. If it helped then upvote the answer.

Comment: @RickardElimää yes, I'm using ```position: fixed``` for my navbar. If you mean I should add ```margin-top: my-nav-height``` to each section, I've tried this method.

Comment: @PullataPraveen didn't help, so sorry. Padding of top of section stays behind the nav.

Comment: can you add your code here to see what is the issue

Comment: Where is `.pc-nav`? Do you mean `.right-nav`?

Comment: @RickarElimää, yes, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

It will allow the community to provide better help